# plupload browse_button doesn't dsiplay dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile, plupload

I've a strange problem with the url of the browse_button. The uploader is in the jquery ready function. When I load the php-page the url of the pickfiles button shows: `192.168.1.230/logins#` which is wrong so i cannot add files. But when i refresh the page it shows the correct url `192.168.1.230/profile#` so I can add files.

It seems that plupload cannot bind the pickfiles button correctly on first load of the page.  Any idea?

---javascript---

```js
$(function(){    
            var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
                runtimes : 'html5',
                browse_button : 'pickfiles',
                max_file_size : '10mb',
                multi_selection : false,
                file_data_name: 'files',
                url : '/profile/upload',
                filters : [
                    {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
                ]
            });           

            uploader.init();
            uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
                uploader.start();
            });

            uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response) {
                $('#errblk' + file.id + " b").html("100%");   
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response.response);
                $('#preview').removeAttr("src").attr('src',obj.filename+ '?' + Math.random());
                $('#errblk').html("");
            });           

});
```

---php-page---

```php
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
         <a style="" data-role="button" id="pickfiles" href="#">
             <?php echo  $this->translate("Change"); ?>
         </a>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a similar problem on a complex page where plupload does not correctly bind the first time. I suspect that something is happening in the wrong order.